# 4.1 parser claims "mismatched input" with simple palindrome grammar

Tags: grammar, antlr4, palindrome

Can't see my mistake here. Given a simple palindrome grammar:

```
// test1.g

grammar test1;

start
    : 'a' start 'a'
    | 'b' start 'b'
    | 'a' 
    | 'b'
    |
    ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

when given the input `aabbbaa`, the generated parser reports:

```
line 1:5 mismatched input 'a' expecting 'b'
```

But it looks like legal input to me. Antlr v4.1.

Comment: Can you include the code where you are constructing your instance of the `test1Parser` and using it to call the `start` method?

Comment: The above is the only code I wrote, all else was generated I think. I'm using TestRig as shown in section 1.2 of the book. But I could be confused, not being a Java programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you did not include a rule like the following:

```
entry : start EOF;
```

By omitting the `EOF`, you've hit a [bug #118](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/118) that can manifest in certain stack-sensitive parsing situations (decision is LL, not SLL). The performance impact of fixing this issue was massive (cannot be understated), so until we find another way to address the problem you'll need to be aware of this and make sure to start parsing with a rule that ends with an explicit `EOF` symbol.

Comment: I'm sure that is in some sense a correct answer, so I'll post a separate question for the completely different incorrect behavior I get when applying your fix.